# jQuery Mobile + Twitter oAuth

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, twitter-oauth

I have a mobile web app that is using jQuery mobile. I am using Twitters API to register users and log them in.

When I load the app I have a splash screen with a button. When you click on the button it directs to the oauth script:

```
<?php
require("lib/twitteroauth.php");
session_start();

// The TwitterOAuth instance
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY', 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET'); 
// Requesting authentication tokens, the parameter is the URL we will be redirected to
$request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken('http://glnce.com/oh/login.php');

// Saving them into the session
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];


// If everything goes well..
if($twitteroauth->http_code==200){
// Let's generate the URL and redirect
$url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']);
header('Location: '. $url);

} else {
// It's a bad idea to kill the script, but we've got to know when there's an error.
die('Something wrong happened.');
}
?>
```

However I get an error when I click on the button from the splash page. It isn't a php error but I am assuming it is a jQuery Mobile issue. I'm also assuming its because I am trying to change the header.

Any thoughts on how to change the header to the $url so that it doesn't open safari  and it stays in my web app?

I know this is vague but I'm not sure how else to explain it. I just need to run this script without it opening a new window.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: It doesn't say. I think its just a jquery mobile error.

Comment: How do you know you are getting an error if it doesn't say anything?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use curl to fetch the page and feed it to the user instead?

Comment: I tried using a basic curl_exec but it is still trying to open the $url in a different window which opens up Safari on the iPhone.

Comment: You need to remove the header line.

Enable return contents in curl. Then show the results to the user.